# When push comes to shove

Tags: traducción, modismos

Una frase muy frecuente en inglés es **"when push comes to shove"** y se usa para determinar el momento en que una situación alcanza su punto crítico o el momento en el que es indispensable pasar a la acción.

Mi mejor aproximación en español es *"a la hora de la verdad"*.

¿Existe en español una expresión idiomática con un significado cercano a la expresión en inglés?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A la hora de la verdad" me parece una buena traducción. Sin embargo, también existe un sentido negativo de *when push comes to shove* que hace que "a la hora de la verdad" no termine ser la mejor alternativa en algunos casos. Otras expresiones que sí expresan este matiz son:

- Cuando las cosas se ponen/pongan feas...
- Cuando las circunstancias aprietan/aprieten...

En estas expresiones se deberá usar el indicativo para referirse a un hecho general:

> Cuando las cosas se ponen feas, siempre viene corriendo a pedirme ayuda.

En cambio, se deberá usar el subjuntivo para referirse a una situación hipotética en el futuro (o que aún no ocurre):

> Cuando las cosas se pongan feas, ya vendrás corriendo a pedirme ayuda.

Comment: Cierto. Esta expresión también reemplaza en sentido negativo a **"when the going gets tough"** que es como la que explicas en tu respuesta +1

Comment: @DGaleano De hecho también se usa *when the going gets **rough*** que vendría siendo lo mismo en temas de que las clases se *complican.*

Comment: This is really a question not an answer ... wouldn't just "a la hora" be sufficient? Standing on its own it obviously has wider meaning, but in context "la hora" is often used interchangeably for "the moment" or even "the current moment", and "a la _pal._de_tiempo_" is at that time. So roughly in context "a la hora" would mean "at the [important] moment".

Comment: @robertotomás Not really. I cannot think of any situation where "a la hora" is okay. There are some idiomatic expressions involving only "hora", such as "en su (debida) hora", "a la hora de [verb]..." or "ya va siendo hora de que...", but simply "a la hora" doesn't work in this case. As a side note, you can say "a la hora" to mean "per hour", but of course that's a whole different meaning.

Answer (score 3):

*push*, visto como sustantivo, vendría siendo el *impulso*.
Es difícil hallar una expresión idiomática con las mismas palabras.

En cierta forma, visto como una discusión entre dos o más personas, parten con un *impulso* y luego con un *empujón*, entonces *when push comes to shove* vendría siendo lo que tú sugieres: *llegó la hora de la verdad.*

---

En cualquier caso, se dice que esta expresión posee su derivado del Rubgy, aunque no hay fuentes que acrediten la veracidad.

[»When push comes to shove«](http://www.chacha.com/question/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-%27when-push-comes-to-shove%27)

---

Como dato extra, en Chile este término se conoce idiomáticamente como *a la hora de los **quiubos***, en donde ***quiubos*** es la contracción de ***qué hubo***, o sea *a la hora de rendir cuentas.*

Comment: I think it is helpful to point out that a push can be quite gentle whereas a shove is more violent. So it means the moment when you have to really take action. I think it is extremely unlikely to come from rugby.

Comment: Nunca había oído de "la hora de los quiubos". No es usual por estos lados pero me gusta como suena. +1

Comment: @DGaleano Sí, por eso di alusión a que se usa mucho en mi país.

Answer (score 1):

Una expresión para las situaciones que describes podría ser:
"Esto ya pasó de castaño a oscuro" -  Las cosas ya pasaron de la raya, y se debe tomar una acción para corregir la situación. También se usa "Esto ya se pasó de la raya".

O también, "Antes que la sangre llegue al río", tomar una acción antes de que las cosas empeoren y se tornen realmente malas.

Otra: "Fue la gota que colmó el vaso", una situación que estaba mal pero dentro de ciertos límites, se vuelve de pronto insoportable/inaguantable.

En mi opinión, "la hora de la verdad" se dice cuando es un momento decisivo, pero no necesariamente quiere decir mejorar una situación que deba arreglarse.

Comment: También "Al momento de los bifes"... aunque muchas veces con connotaciones sexuales.